# SQL Complex Filter/Join Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm a novice at SQL and I think this is a relatively basic query but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have two tables.  One has group membership and the other details about the group.  The key field between the two is `Group`.

Membership looks like this.

```
Person    EffectiveDate    Group

Mary        8/10/2017        A
Joe         8/05/2017        A
Peter       9/01/2017        B
Mike        9/2/2017         B
Alice       9/2/2017         B
Joe         9/10/2017        B
Pam         9/3/2017         C
```

Note that there are two entries for Joe because he ***changed*** groups.

GroupInformation Looks like this:

```
Group     FullName     Location    Color

A          Panthers     New York    Blue
B          Steelers     London      Orange
C          Archers      Moscow      Yellow
```

I want to run a query that, on any given day, will give me the individual's group membership along with team details.

So, I want to find the line with the `MAX(EffectiveDate)` in Membership for each individual person on the date run and left join the GroupInformation table on key `Group`

If I ran the query on 9/4 I'd get this:

```
Person    EffectiveDate   Group   FullName    Location   Color

Mary        8/10/2017        A     Panthers     New York    Blue
Joe         8/05/2017        A     Panthers     New York    Blue
Peter       9/01/2017        B     Steelers     London      Orange
Mike        9/2/2017         B     Steelers     London      Orange
Alice       9/2/2017         B     Steelers     London      Orange
Pam         9/3/2017         C     Archers      Moscow      Yellow
```

If I ran the query on 9/13 I'd get this:

```
Person    EffectiveDate   Group   FullName    Location   Color

Mary        8/10/2017        A     Panthers     New York    Blue
Peter       9/01/2017        B     Steelers     London      Orange
Mike        9/2/2017         B     Steelers     London      Orange
Alice       9/2/2017         B     Steelers     London      Orange
Joe         9/10/2017        B     Steelers     London      Orange
Pam         9/3/2017         C     Archers      Moscow      Yellow
```

Note that the difference between the two query results is Joe.  The 9/4 run has him in Group A joining on 8/5 where the 9/13 run has him in Group B which he joined on 9/10.

My query code is as follow:

```
Select s.Person,
       s.Group,
       s.EffectiveDate,
       g.FullName,
       g.Location,
       g.Color

From   Membership s
Join   GroupInformation g
  on   s.Group = g.Group
  and  s.EffectiveDate = (
       Select Max(s1.EffectiveDate)
       From Membership s1
       where s1.Group = g.Group
       and s1.EffectiveDate <= '2017-09-14')
```

However when I run this code I find in my actual data that it omits records.  So if I have 150 records in membership the resulting query join and subquery operations will result in an answer with maybe 80 records.

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Guidance please.

Thanks.

Comment: Your query is restricting records to only those members who have *exactly* the membership date of the most recent member. That's why records are being omitted.

Comment: Tag your question with the datbse you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but using the wrong correlation clause:

```
Select s.Person, s.Group, s.EffectiveDate, g.FullName, g.Location, g.Color
From Membership s Join
     GroupInformation g
     on s.Group = g.Group
WHERE s.EffectiveDate = (Select Max(s1.EffectiveDate)
                         From Membership s1
                         where s1.Person = s.Person and
                               s1.EffectiveDate <= '2017-09-14'
                        );
```

Note that `group` is a very poor name for a column name in SQL, because it is a SQL key word.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Group is just in my example code here on the site.

Comment: can you explain (or refer me to a source) as to why I need  `where s1.Person = s.Person` in the subquery?  I don't intuitively see it.

Comment: @Windstorm1981 `s1.Person = s.Person` makes sure you get the latest EffectiveDate of Joe.  Without the condition, you will get the latest EffectiveDate of a member who last joined the group.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to recharacterize the membership data to group member names as well as dates, then use it as a subquery and join to it in this vein. You're basically saying "give me the max membership date of each person prior to a given date of interest." Caveat: if the EffectiveDate field is strictly 'Date' (rather than a DateTime), it could theoretically still fail if someone changed memberships twice on the same day (no date resolution beyond the day).

Suggest this as a possible alternative (warning this is very hastily thrown together and not tested):

```
select s.person, s.group, s.EffectiveDate, g.FullName,g.location, g.color
  from (select m.person,m.group, max(m.effectivedate) effectivedate
          from Membership m
         where m.EffectiveDate <= '2017-09-14'
         group by m.person,m.group) s
  join GroupInformation g
    on s.group=g.group
```